# Getting error kafka.KafkaInputFormat: can not generate full scan split

Tags: hive, apache-kafka

When querying a Kafka Stream from a Hive External table we are getting at Timeout in Beeline.  Looking in the hive server logs, it's giving these error messages

> 2019-05-01T14:27:09,725  WARN [pool-226-thread-1] kafka.RetryUtils:
>   Retrying (1 of 5) in 1,353ms. java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.partitionsFor(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List;

followed by

> ERROR [08693181-1964-4d87-bf5a-7d628b4f9e43
>   HiveServer2-HttpHandler-Pool: Thread-89] kafka.KafkaInputFormat: can
>   not generate full scan split

Tried sending a simpler JSON structure

Tried with and without the table property

> "kafka.serde.class"="org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.JsonSerDe",

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE rs_table2
(id int,
first_name string,
last_name string)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.kafka.KafkaStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES
("kafka.topic" = "xxxxx", 
"kafka.bootstrap.servers"="xxxxxx:9092",
"kafka.consumer.group.id"="1", 
"session.timeout.ms"="30000",
"kafka.serde.class"="org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.JsonSerDe",
"kafka.consumer.partition.assignment.strategy"="range"
);
```

I expect the query to output the data in the stream

Comment: Did you manually setup Hive Kafka? For the first error, it requires you to distribute kafka client jars to all machines where Hive code runs. Once you fix the classpath, then the InputFormat should be able to work better

Comment: Thanks, it's part of HDInsights on Azure.  Will distribute the Storage Handler Jar to the relevant nodes

Comment: One point of confirmation, I downloaded the kafka-handler-3.1.0.3.1.0.6-1.jar, is that correct?

Comment: According to the error, you need kafka-clients.jar. Preferably a version of it that matches the kafka broker version. I'm not sure if the handler alone includes those or not

Comment: Looks like the kafka handler jars available for download require kafka client v2, whereas Azure installs Kafka v1.11.  I assume this is a show stopper?

Comment: It shouldn't be. Kafka 2.0 clients can work with 1.1 brokers